# How can i move this javascript outside of my aspx view and into a seperate js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net-mvc project and I have this code sitting in one of hte views:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function () {

        var locations = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.LocationArray) %>;
```

I want to move this code into a seperate js file (for reasons that are not pertinent to this question) but i realize that i can't because of the code sitting in between the <% %>

Any suggestions for how i can "inject" this into a seperate js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitly access this variable in your other javascript file. I prefer to prefix the variable with g to indicate that it is a global variable. Pay attention to the order of loading your javascript.

```
<Script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){    
  var gLocation=<%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.LocationArray) %>;  
});
</script>
<script src="scriptWhichUseThisVariable.js"></script>
```

You may also pass this variable to functions written in your external javascript file.

```
$(function(){   
  var gLocation=<%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.LocationArray) %>;
  MyFunctionInCustomJSFile(gLocation);
});
```

Make sure that you load the javascript file which has the function `MyFunctionInCustomJSFile` defined inside it. Also make sure to access it inside block of code which executes after the above code finishes execution.

Comment: Overall, good answer, but I'd caution against just prefixing global variables with `g`. You might not be the only one who thought of that, so all the dangers of global namespace pollution are still there. Far better to create a new object (`var MyAwesomeNamespace = MyAwesomeNamespace || {};`) and then assign your globals there (`MyAwesomeNamespace.Location = <%= ... %>`)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `locations` value in the local file BEFORE the external file runs. As the value is populated server-side, you don't need it nested in `.ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's data and not code, one option is to load it via AJAX at runtime.

Comment: I wanted to avoid having a seperate ajax call